# $wp_scripts does not include all plugin scripts

Tags: wordpress

I am working on combining my JS files in functions.php. I am accessing $wp_scripts in a function that I have added to 'wp_footer': `add_action('wp_footer', 'removeCombinedScripts');`

$wp_scripts does not included all of my scripts though. There are various plugin scripts that are not there.

Comment: All plugins should use `wp_enqueue_script`. so you can access in `$wp_scripts`

Comment: Maybe some plugins use the same wp_footer hook, try priority like `add_action('wp_footer', 'removeCombinedScripts', 99);`

Comment: Thanks Jaydip. Using priority provides me a much larger list of scripts.